# How to group by date without performing aggregate function on stock data

Tags: python, pandas, date, group-by, pandas-groupby

I currently have the following data frame: https://i.stack.imgur.com/doa0q.png

I want my data frame to have the following format (the AAPL, MSFT and FB should all be aligned underneath each other):

2019-04-12: AAPL

MSFT

FB

I have tried to groupby date but everywhere online then performs an aggregate function which I don't want to do. How can I go about achieving my desired output/what do I need to read into further?

Answer (score 1):

If it is only for you to get an easier overview, you can create a hierarchical index like this:

```
df.reset_index().set_index(['Date', 'Ticker'])
```

However printing it out like this is not supported in pandas itself. The rationale is most of all that it would be a nightmare to read back in, so it is only useful for presentations.

Comment: it's so that I can do a train-test split on the dates itself. That way the test set would be x% (depending on the size I choose) of each ticker, rather than x% of the whole dataset

Comment: You should take a look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html. It has a parameter stratify, I have not personally used it but it looks like it could do what you want out of the box.